# c++ struct of vector of struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

Im trying to get a better understanding of structs and I could use some help. Im trying to create a struct which contains a vector of structs, but Im having trouble linking them together. So far I got:

```
struct Vehicle{
    string LicensePlate;
    string VehicleType;
    vector<string> DamageType;
    int EstFixDays;
}veh;

struct DailyCustomers{
    string date;
    struct Vehicle vehicleList;
}dlc;

int main(){
  vector<Vehicle> vehicleList;
  struct DailyCustomers dlc;
  dlc.date = fileVector[1];
  for (int i = 1; i < fileVector.size(); i++){
      stringDevide(fileVector[i]);
      struct Vehicle veh;
      veh.LicensePlate = licensePlate;
      veh.VehicleType = vehicleType;
      veh.DamageType = vehicleDamageType;  
      veh.EstFixDays = est; 
      vehicleList.push_back(veh);
  }
  dlc.vehicleList = veh;
}
```

My program seems to be working fine, as the struct linking doesnt affect it, but Im not sure if I linked them together correctly. Should the last line be inside the `for` loop?

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `struct`  -- You're overusing the `struct` keyword.  The only place it's required is when you are defining the `struct`.

Comment: There is no 'fileVector' defined anywhere.

Comment: 'veh' variable is local to 'for' loop - haw can you assign it outside the loop? I am pretty sure this code snippet is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't created a struct containing a vector of structs. All you've done is created a struct which contains a struct. You do have a vector of structs but that is in main, not in any struct.

You also have miscellaneous other issues, global variables you aren't using and unnecessary `struct` uses.

Here's how you should do it

```
struct Vehicle {
    string LicensePlate;
    string VehicleType;
    vector<string> DamageType;
    int EstFixDays;
};

struct DailyCustomers {
    string date;
    vector<Vehicle> vehicleList; // a vector of structs inside a struct
};

int main() {
    DailyCustomers dlc;
    dlc.date = fileVector[1];
    for (int i = 1; i < fileVector.size(); i++) {
        stringDevide(fileVector[i]);
        Vehicle veh;
        veh.LicensePlate = licensePlate;
        veh.VehicleType = vehicleType;
        veh.DamageType = vehicleDamageType;  
        veh.EstFixDays = est; 
        dlc.vehicleList.push_back(veh);
    }
}
```